# PostgreSQL on Linux, running an SQL file for Windows

Tags: linux, postgresql, windows, psql

I use Linux to restore a [PostgreSQL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PostgreSQL) database from an SQL file, but this file was dumped from Windows.

Then the inserts look like \N and tab separators.

How can I import this Windows-born file, from the Linux command line?

Options for run: `psql -d database \< backupFromWindows.sql` without errors.

Comment: Restoring a SQL dump should work the same on Windows or Linux. What is the error you get? And how exactly was the dump taken?

Comment: into sql file the insert format if litle different. \N instead semicolon and other rare characters.

Comment: How is this not a duplicate?

Answer (score 0):

Eureka!

- In the Linux terminal, after logging in as the *postgres* user, open a *psql* console
- Then \connect mydatabase
- Then \i "/path/to/file.sql"

The */path/to/file.sql* should be a */tmp* path or another with the right permissions for the *postgres* user.

Comment: See also *[Is it ever correct to have a space before a question or exclamation mark?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/4645/is-it-ever-correct-to-have-a-space-before-a-question-or-exclamation-mark#comment206109_4645)*.

Comment: Learn English it is include in my year goals I doing it viewing captions in the netflix series and Youtube videos